# What is the difference between returning a Promise with .then() and without .then()?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I am trying to learn about **JavaScript Promises**, and so far I have come across a lot of code where either a naked (for lack of better word) Promise is returned, i.e. one without any call to `.then()`, and code where `.then()` is attached.

What is the difference between the two and when do you use one over the other?

### Naked Promise

```
myfn1() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        //...resolve or reject
    }
}
```

### Promise with `.then()` attached

```
myfn2() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        //...resolve or reject
    }
    .then((res) => {
        //...do something upon resolve
    })
}
```

Comment: you answered it in the question itself i guess

Comment: @RahulSingh If you think he answered himself, then explain how he answered it. I think he may be asking what the purpose of using a promise is if you are not going to use a .then.

Comment: `Promise.then()` returns another Promise object. I would say that's the fundamental difference.

Comment: @kojow7 when using a  promise without then you cannot assign value to a user defined variable to be used inside of a template or make manipulations on the data with is returned by the http call which returns a priomise. you can only resolve or reject the data without then

Comment: @RahulSingh That's not true. `const promise = new Promise(..); promise.then(...)` works well.

Comment: @OmriAharon you have to make a then call to the promise any how right. without then it wont work

Comment: @RahulSingh, You said that you are only able to resolve or reject the data without then. This is the purpose of the .then/.catch combination is it not?

Comment: @RahulSingh You make the call to the promise, but nowhere does it say you have to `then/catch` immediately.

Comment: Well, quite obviously the one code literally "*does something upon resolve*" and the other doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you're using `then` you're determining where you would like to handle the data (or error) resolved by the promise. If you chain it with `then` immediately, then I guess it's fine for you to immediately address it.

But you might want to just get the promise itself, and take care of the result someplace else. Maybe you have a service file, whose sole purpose is to create HTTP requests, but you want to handle the data under a different scope - the scope of the calling function:

```
// service.js
callServer() {
    return new Promise(...)
}

// file.js
callServer().then( /* there's a different scope here */ )
```

Maybe you even want to get several promises and then use `Promise.all(promisesArray)` and only act once all promises have been resolved:

```
const movies = getMovies(); // promise
const actors = getActors(); // promise
const directors = getDirectors(); // promise

Promise([movies, actors, directors]).then(_ => /* handle data */ );
```

There could be many reasons depending on the application.

Comment: Hi Omri, this makes a lot of sense. If not too much of a hassle, could you clarify a bit or provide a mini example of handling data under a different scope and the possible advantages?

Comment: Actually, not necessary, if you have functionality that's only available in one scope, then you may need to handle your data in that scope. makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

The main difference is that you'd be able to use the result of the operation (usually async) defined from the previous promise chain. Consider the following code:

```js
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  // we simulate an async op using setTimeout that returns an object
  setTimeout(() => resolve({ status: 'ok' }), 2300);
  // the value of res is defined as the value that is resolved from the previous promise chain, so in this case the object { status: 'ok'}
}).then(res => {
  // do something with resolved result
  console.log(res)
})
```

Without the `then` method, you won't be able to get the value of the return value defined in the previous promise chain.

Answer (score 1):

The low level and basic difference between the two is that a different promise is being returned.

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    //...resolve or reject
}
```

returns the promise created by the call to `new Promise`.

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    //...resolve or reject
}
.then((res) => {
    //...do something upon ** fulfillment **
})
```

returns the promise returned by the call to the `then` method of the new Promise.

If the promise on which `then` is called (created by `new Promise` above) becomes rejected, the promise returned by `then` with a single parameter is rejected with the same reason: a `then` supplied onFulfilled reaction handler is never called.

If the first promise is fulfilled, the callback supplied as first parameter to `then` is called, and the promise returned by `then` is settled according to the callback's behavior:

- If the callback returns a value which is not a promise, the promise returned by `then` is fulfilled with the same value, or
- If the callback throws an error, the promise returned by `then` is rejected with the value of the error thrown,
- If the callback returns a promise (either a native promise or one from library code) the promise returned from `then` is linked to it and will ultimately adopt the same settled state and fulfilled value or rejection reason as the promise returned by the callback.

Deciding to return a promise created by `new Promise`, or one returned by the last `then` or `catch` clause in a chain of promises, from a function depends on the design of the function, not the design of Promise objects.